# Verizon Actiontec MI424WR - No communication between wired and wireless network

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, fios

I have a Verizon-branded Actiontec MI424WR wireless modem/router. Machines connected to the router over WiFi can communicate with each other. Machines connected to the router over Ethernet can communicate with each other. However, machines connected to the router via Ethernet are unable to communicate with machines connected to the router over WiFi.

How can I configure the MI424WR so that machines connected over WiFi and Ethernet can communicate with each other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Machines connected over WiFi and Ethernet can communicate with each other if the `IGMP Proxy` is disabled.

The `IGMP Proxy` can be disabled from http://192.168.1.1/index.cgi?active_page=6059 (assuming the router's IP address is `192.168.1.1`).

Source: https://forums.verizon.com/t5/Fios-Internet/Communication-between-wired-and-wireless-network-on-actiontec/m-p/762067#M52113